# How to change the usb name of Atmel 32u4?

Tags: usb

I want to change my Arduino Leonardo's name that Windows shows me when it's plugged in.

I know that i have to change its firmware to change the name but I cant find firmware for it on the Internet.

On Arduino Mega, I have changed it with a downloaded firmware via flip, but I can't change the file because it's a .hex.

Comment: you can change the hex, if you're brave enough

Comment: Start looking here for the actual implementation https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina/Descriptors.c and at the Makefile for a start towards building from source.  You may be able to modify the .hex (the strings appear to be fixed length and padded with spaces) but will need a tool which fixes the checksums - possibly you can objcopy to a flat binary and back to hex.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino '32U4 bootloader, Caterina, can be found under `hardware/arduino/bootloaders/caterina`. It requires [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/140928/html/) in order to build.

With the technical part aside, note that you are not allowed to use the USB IDs assigned to Arduino LLC with products you intend to distribute under another name. You will need to acquire your own vendor ID from the [USB-IF](http://www.usb.org/) if you want to do so.