# Pro Micro and LilyPad USB

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

Is there a difference between Pro Micro 8MHz 3.3V and LilyPad USB bootloaders?

Both are based on 32U4 running at 8 MHz.

Comment: I'm curious as to what issues you're having with them exactly...

Comment: I am not sure which one to pick for my application.

Comment: Pick whichever one has the form factor that is most appropriate, then replace the firmware with any you like.

Comment: Thank you. I learned form Sparkfun that they modified these bootloaders reset. Their document which explains this change is available from this link: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/32U4Note.pdf Where can I get a version of these bootloaders without these changes.  Thanks

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16731/how-to-change-the-usb-name-of-atmel-32u4/16736#16736